# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException occurring only in updated Samsung Devices with Android 9.0

Tags: java, android, androidx, samsung-galaxy

So, the apparently, the app crashes whenever the user tries to open it on their Samsung Galaxy devices with latest 9.0 update. I've tested the app on devices with android 9.0 and it appears to work fine on nearly all the devices I tested it on. It's Samsung only problem I guess?

### Here's the stack traces from Play Console:

```
  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.b (FragmentManager.java:3)
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentHostCallback.a (FragmentHostCallback.java:3)
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.a (FragmentManagerImpl.java:19)
  at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.ar.a (ar.java:15)
  at androidx.core.widget.AutoSizeableTextView.a (AutoSizeableTextView.java:20)
  at androidx.core.widget.AutoSizeableTextView.run (AutoSizeableTextView.java:8)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass (BaseDexClassLoader.java:134)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:379)
  at androidx.appcompat.view.StandaloneActionMode.loadClass (StandaloneActionMode.java:4)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:312)
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.b (FragmentManager.java:3)
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentHostCallback.a (FragmentHostCallback.java:3)
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.a (FragmentManagerImpl.java:19)
  at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.ar.a (ar.java:15)
  at androidx.core.widget.AutoSizeableTextView.a (AutoSizeableTextView.java:20)
  at androidx.core.widget.AutoSizeableTextView.run (AutoSizeableTextView.java:8)
```

Above stack traces is all I have in my play console, along with the information of devices it is occurring on. I'm particularly concerned about this error because more people will be upgrading to latest One UI from Samsung.
[Here's screenshot from Play Console showing devices with errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GYmKM.jpg)

[image]

According to me it is unable to find a certain class? AutoSizeableTextView maybe? I'm using androidx libraries in the app, along with MaterialComponents theme.

Comment: Before posting the stacktrace you should de-obfuscate it (method names, line-numbers), otherwise it is of limited use.

Comment: Yes I've already uploaded deobfuscation files as you can see in the screenshot. It's Google's dependencies so maybe they've already obfuscated it? Even I'm unable to know what the problem is because of that. Also, if there is any way to de-obfuscate the files it would be awesome? I do not have a Samsung device to actually see the real stack trace, I've been trying to find one. It works fine on all devices with Android 9.0, except the updated Samsung One UI devices.

Comment: Your problem is that the stacktrace is missing the message which contains the info which class failed to load. Furthermore the line numbers are invalid (I assume you have Proguard configured to remove them). As we have neither the message with the class-name nor the line number it is nearly impossible to understand what is going wrong. Looks like you need a physical Samsung phone or one in a remote "device farm" (remote Android devices as a service for debugging).

Comment: do you have map sdk in your application?

Comment: No there is no map sdk in my app. @Robert I can see other errors in Google's ANR's and Crashes with no problem, with line numbers and everything. Only this is the error that is coming in this way.

Answer (score 0):

maybe ProGuard rules went too far?
please check `AutoSizeableTextView` dependencies have (legacy in your case) `android.support.*`. This could be a problem. Alternatively, which is not recommended(and it is not a solution), you can check if your app has missing dependency at runtime

```
private boolean hasMissingClassFoo() {

    try {
        Class.forName("com.your.domain.myClassFoo");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException x) {
        x.printStackTrace();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: But how do I actually check if it fixed the problem? I do not have any Samsung device at the moment, I've been trying to find one from so much time. Is there any way I can simulate this on emulator or other physical device? Also in the stack trace it is showing androidx dependencies, so AutoSizeableTextView is not legacy in this case. And this issue is particularly related to Samsung Devices only. I've tested it on Android 9.0 devices, works totally fine. Cannot be problem with obfuscation, if it was the problem, then it would have not worked altogether.

Comment: you can track events, exceptions with firebase + crashlytics

Comment: Yes but I'm kind of already doing that with Google Play Crash analytics right?